# The passive form of 'believe' vs 'consider'

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Example :

1. Each culture has special things that are believed to bring good luck to people.
2. Each culture has special things that are considered bringing good luck to people.

Question :

1. Are they both grammatical?
2. Do they have difference in meaning?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is fine, but the second is not.  You would have to re-write that as:

'Each culture has special things that are considered to bring good luck to people.'

Since the second is not 'grammatical', its meaning is, perhaps, ambiguous, but if someone said the second sentence to me, I would interpret it to mean the same as the first.

Alan.